# Clean way to find ActiveRecord objects by id in the order specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, find, rails-activerecord

I want to obtain an array of ActiveRecord objects given an array of ids.

I assumed that

```
Object.find([5,2,3])
```

Would return an array with object 5, object 2, then object 3 in that order, but instead I get an array ordered as object 2, object 3 and then object 5.

The ActiveRecord Base [find method API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002208) mentions that you shouldn't expect it in the order provided (other documentation doesn't give this warning).

One potential solution was given in [Find by array of ids in the same order?](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/158dc2d879b2fb1), but the order option doesn't seem to be valid for SQLite.

I can write some ruby code to sort the objects myself (either somewhat simple and poorly scaling or better scaling and more complex), but is there A Better Way?

Comment: Where are those id's coming from? If it is the UI (via a user selecting them) then scaling shouldn't be an issue, that is the user is unlikely to spend time selecting 1000's of ids).

If it's the database (e.g. from a join table), could you store the order in the join table and issue the find based on that?

Comment: It looks like this is [no longer true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728424/1507845) in Rails 5.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not that MySQL and other DBs sort things on their own, it's that they don't sort them.  When you call `Model.find([5, 2, 3])`, the SQL generated is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM models WHERE models.id IN (5, 2, 3)
```

This doesn't specify an order, just the set of records you want returned.  It turns out that generally MySQL will return the database rows in `'id'` order, but there's no guarantee of this.

The only way to get the database to return records in a guaranteed order is to add an order clause.  If your records will always be returned in a particular order, then you can add a sort column to the db and do `Model.find([5, 2, 3], :order => 'sort_column')`.  If this isn't the case, you'll have to do the sorting in code:

```
ids = [5, 2, 3]
records = Model.find(ids)
sorted_records = ids.collect {|id| records.detect {|x| x.id == id}}
```

Comment: Another solution that is more performant than using #detect to avoid O(N) performance: records = Model.find(ids).group_by(&:id); sorted_records = ids.map { |id| records[id].first }

Answer (score 10):

Based on my previous comment to Jeroen van Dijk you can do this more efficiently and in two lines using `each_with_object`

```
result_hash = Model.find(ids).each_with_object({}) {|result,result_hash| result_hash[result.id] = result }
ids.map {|id| result_hash[id]}
```

For reference here is the benchmark i used

```
ids = [5,3,1,4,11,13,10]
results = Model.find(ids)

Benchmark.measure do 
  100000.times do 
    result_hash = results.each_with_object({}) {|result,result_hash| result_hash[result.id] = result }
    ids.map {|id| result_hash[id]}
  end
end.real
#=>  4.45757484436035 seconds
```

Now the other one

```
ids = [5,3,1,4,11,13,10]
results = Model.find(ids)
Benchmark.measure do 
  100000.times do 
    ids.collect {|id| results.detect {|result| result.id == id}}
  end
end.real
# => 6.10875988006592
```

**Update**

You can do this in most using order and case statements, here is a class method you could use.

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]
  ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "end"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end

#   User.where(:id => [3,2,1]).order_by_ids([3,2,1]).map(&:id) 
#   #=> [3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 8):

Apparently mySQL and other DB management system sort things on their own. I think that you can bypass that doing :

```
ids = [5,2,3]
@things = Object.find( ids, :order => "field(id,#{ids.join(',')})" )
```

Comment: That was the answer suggested in the link "Find by arrays of id in the same order?", but it doesn't seem to work for SQLite.

Comment: This no longer works. For more recent Rails: `Object.where(id: ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join ','})")`

Comment: Improved: `Object.where(id: ids).order(ids.present? && "field(id, #{ids.join ','})")`. This prevents a SQL error if the IDs array is empty or nil.

Answer (score 6):

A portable solution would be to use an SQL CASE statement in your ORDER BY. You can use pretty much any expression in an ORDER BY and a CASE can be used as an inlined lookup table. For example, the SQL you're after would look like this:

```
select ...
order by
    case id
    when 5 then 0
    when 2 then 1
    when 3 then 2
    end
```

That's pretty easy to generate with a bit of Ruby:

```
ids = [5, 2, 3]
order = 'case id ' + (0 .. ids.length).map { |i| "when #{ids[i]} then #{i}" }.join(' ') + ' end'
```

The above assumes that you're working with numbers or some other safe values in `ids`; if that's not the case then you'd want to use [`connection.quote`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote) or one of the [ActiveRecord SQL sanitizer methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql) to properly quote your `ids`.

Then use the `order` string as your ordering condition:

```
Object.find(ids, :order => order)
```

or in the modern world:

```
Object.where(:id => ids).order(order)
```

This is a bit verbose but it should work the same with any SQL database and it isn't that difficult to hide the ugliness.

Comment: I did it with `Object.order('case id ' + ids.each_with_index.map { |id, i| "when #{id} then #{i}" }.join(' ') + ' end')`

Comment: or to sql injection escape, put this in the map block: `sanitize_sql_array(["when ? then ? ", id, i])` (works within an AR model)

Comment: @nruth: There was an unstated assumption that `ids` contained numbers, assumptions are a bad idea (doubly so when they're not explicit) so I've hopefully cleared that up.

Comment: @muistooshort it's still a good answer, and generally a reasonable assumption, especially in 2013. But with javascript front-ends and uuids in fashion it seemed worth a mention, as Google points here for solving the ordering problem.

Answer (score 4):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039262/1103543), I just released a gem ([order_as_specified](https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified)) that allows you to do native SQL ordering like this:

```
Object.where(id: [5, 2, 3]).order_as_specified(id: [5, 2, 3])
```

Just tested and it works in SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

Justin Weiss wrote a [blog article about this problem](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/04/20/how-to-select-database-records-in-an-arbitrary-order/) just two days ago.

It seems to be a good approach to tell the database about the preferred order and load all records sorted in that order directly from the database. Example from his [blog article](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/04/20/how-to-select-database-records-in-an-arbitrary-order/):

```
# in config/initializers/find_by_ordered_ids.rb
module FindByOrderedIdsActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def find_ordered(ids)
      order_clause = "CASE id "
      ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
        order_clause << "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index} "
      end
      order_clause << "ELSE #{ids.length} END"
      where(id: ids).order(order_clause)
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.include(FindByOrderedIdsActiveRecordExtension)
```

That allows you to write:

```
Object.find_ordered([2, 1, 3]) # => [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Nice drop-in solution but only applies to the `id`. Would be nice to be able to dynamically determine the attribute to order by, like `uid` or something.

Comment: @JoshPinter: Just add a parameter `field_name` to the method and use that `field_name` instead of `"CASE id"` like this: `"CASE #{field_name} "`

Comment: Yep, thanks for the follow-up. Was thinking more of allowing for `find_ordered_by_uid(uids)` but it's just building off what you said. Cheers.

Comment: Recommend changing the name of the method to `find_by_ordered_ids` to be more explicit and match the name of the module file.

Comment: If using a a different field than `id` that isn't an `Integer` then make sure you wrap `#{id}` with parenthesis, like so `"WHEN '#{uid}' THEN #{index} ". Can't thank you enough @spickermann for this little snippet of code - works great!

Comment: if you're using uuid strings because of distribution (accepting ids from clients) they need escaping or you're looking at sql injection attacks. Something like `sanitize_sql_array(["when ? then ? ", id, index])` in an AR model.

Comment: @alexandrecosta You can use `return where('null') if ids.blank?` and it'll return an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation` when `ids` is an empty Array.

Comment: I would recommend to use ActiveRecord's [`none`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none) scope instead of `where('null')`.

Comment: This will create an ambiguous query when using JOINs. To fix that use `order_clause = "CASE #{self.table_name}.id "` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a performant (hash-lookup, not O(n) array search as in detect!) one-liner, as a method:

```
def find_ordered(model, ids)
  model.find(ids).map{|o| [o.id, o]}.to_h.values_at(*ids)
end

# We get:
ids = [3, 3, 2, 1, 3]
Model.find(ids).map(:id)          == [1, 2, 3]
find_ordered(Model, ids).map(:id) == ids
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (probably more efficient) way to do it in Ruby:

```
ids = [5, 2, 3]
records_by_id = Model.find(ids).inject({}) do |result, record| 
  result[record.id] = record
  result
end
sorted_records = ids.map {|id| records_by_id[id] }
```

Comment: you can use each_with_object to make this code two lines FWIW. also did some benchmarking and it looks like this code is _much_ faster if you're iterating over a large set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't know of the existence of #each_with_object (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). Is there a significant difference between the above #inject and #each_with_object approach?

Comment: Nope, each_with_object is essentially the same as inject except you don't have to return the object your modifying (in your case `result`) at the end of your block. It simplifies building hashes IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest thing I could come up with:

```
ids = [200, 107, 247, 189]
results = ModelObject.find(ids).group_by(&:id)
sorted_results = ids.map {|id| results[id].first }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@things = [5,2,3].map{|id| Object.find(id)}
```

This is probably the easiest way, assuming you don't have too many objects to find, since it requires a trip to the database for each id.

Comment: you shouldn't do this (N+1 queries)

Comment: It's N queries, not N+1.  There are much better ways to do this, but as I said, this is the easiest.  For performance, look them all up, then dump them in a hash with the ids as keys.