# How to select where ID in Array Rails ActiveRecord without exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find

When I have array of ids, like

```
ids = [2,3,5]
```

and I perform

```
Comment.find(ids)
```

everything works fine. But when there is id that doesn't exist, I get an exception. This occurs generaly when I get list of IDs that match some filter and than I do something like

```
current_user.comments.find(ids)
```

This time I may have a valid comment ID, which however does not belong to given User, so it is not found and I get an exception.

I've tried `find(:all, ids)`, but it returns all of the records.

The only way I can do it now is

```
current_user.comments.select { |c| ids.include?(c.id) }
```

But that seems to me like super inefficient solution.

Is there better way to select *ID in Array* without getting exception on non-existing record?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

If it is just avoiding the exception you are worried about, the "find_all_by.." family of functions works without throwing exceptions.

```
Comment.find_all_by_id([2, 3, 5])
```

will work even if some of the ids don't exist.  This works in the

```
user.comments.find_all_by_id(potentially_nonexistent_ids)
```

case as well.

#### Update: Rails 4

```
Comment.where(id: [2, 3, 5])
```

Comment: this is my preferred solution, it seems cleaner than the exception handling route

Comment: As another extension to this, should you need to chain complex conditions, you could even do Comment.all(:conditions => ["approved and id in (?)", [1,2,3]])

Comment: this will be deprecated in Rails 4: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Comment: @JonathanLin is correct, mjnissim's answer should be preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11457025/33226

Comment: This returns an `Array` instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which limits what you can do with it afterwards. `Comment.where(id: [2, 3, 5])` does return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: this is deprecated but Comment.where(id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) does the job

Comment: thank you - how to protect from sql injection - how can one escape the array?

Answer (score 151):

**Update: This answer is more relevant for Rails 4.x**

Do this:

```
current_user.comments.where(:id=>[123,"456","Michael Jackson"])
```

The stronger side of this approach is that it returns a `Relation` object, to which you can join more `.where` clauses, `.limit` clauses, etc., which is very helpful. It also allows non-existent IDs without throwing exceptions.

The newer Ruby syntax would be:

```
current_user.comments.where(id: [123, "456", "Michael Jackson"])
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming the `where` syntax when comparing to an array. I thought I might have to code the SQL with an `IN` statement, but this looks cleaner and is an easy replacement for the deprecated `scoped_by_id`.

Comment: What is this called and how does it work? Is it Rails magic?! As a colleague commented, its like 'comparing an integer with an object list".

Answer (score 29):

If you need more control (perhaps you need to state the table name) you can also do the following:

```
Model.joins(:another_model_table_name)
  .where('another_model_table_name.id IN (?)', your_id_array)
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the order of the `your_id_array` when you get the objects back?

Comment: @JoshPinter I don't think this is a reliable way to expect the database to return things in the same order. Perhaps add a ORDER BY query at the end to ensure the right order of things.

Comment: @JonathanLin Thanks for the response Jonathan. You're certainly right. Using an `ORDER BY` won't work in my situation because the order is not based on an attribute. However, there is a way to do it via SQL (so it's fast) and someone has even created a gem for it. Check out this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801824/clean-way-to-find-activerecord-objects-by-id-in-the-order-specified/29785864#comment52840252_29785864

Answer (score 16):

Now .find and .find_by_id methods are deprecated in rails 4. So instead we can use below:

```
Comment.where(id: [2, 3, 5])
```

It will work even if some of the ids don't exist. This works in the

```
user.comments.where(id: avoided_ids_array)
```

Also for excluding ID's

```
Comment.where.not(id: [2, 3, 5])
```

Comment: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders .find and .find_by_id methods are NOT deprecated in rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid exceptions killing your app you should catch those exceptions and treat them the way you wish, defining the behavior for you app on those situations where the id is not found.

```
begin
  current_user.comments.find(ids)
rescue
  #do something in case of exception found
end
```

Here's [more info](http://ruby.activeventure.com/programmingruby/book/tut_exceptions.html) on exceptions in ruby.

Comment: yep this solves the problem, but it's not really a clean solution

Comment: If you're going to catch an exception you should declare the exception you expect to catch, otherwise you risk it catching something you weren't expecting and hiding an actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it in named_scope if You want to put there others conditions

for example include some other model:

> named_scope 'get_by_ids',  lambda { |ids| { :include => [:comments], :conditions => ["comments.id IN (?)", ids] } }