# how do you perform a SQL find in (?) call?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, conditional-statements

This doesn't seem to be working :

```
@zip = %w[07005, 07034, 07035]

CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["zip_code IN (?)", @zip])

=> [ ]
```

However, if I do a simple find_by with the second zip code, it returns a result :

```
CardSignup.find_by_zip_code("07034")

=> Object<x01231 ..
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of the array is incorrect. The way you have it at the moment the commas are part of each array object:

```
>> %w[07005, 07034, 07035]
=> ["07005,", "07034,", "07035"]
```

You should implement this with the commas removed:

```
>> %w{07005 07034 07035}
=> ["07005", "07034", "07035"]
```

or:

```
>> [07005, 07034, 07035]
=> [07005, 07034, 07035]
```

So the full implementation is:

```
@zip = %w{07005 07034 07035}

CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["zip_code IN (?)", @zip])

=> [Object<x01231 ..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Don't use comma in %w[07005, 07034, 07035]

Just use  %w[07005 07034 07035]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CardSignup.find_by_zip_code(@zip)
```

Edit (from comments):

[How to select where ID in Array Rails ActiveRecord without exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441791/how-to-select-where-id-in-array-rails-activerecord-without-exception)

```
@zip = ["07005", "07034", "07035"]
CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["zip_code IN (?)", @zip])

CardSignup.find_all_by_zip_code(["07005", "07034", "07035"])
```

Comment: How can I alter that syntax to include an `OR` statement in it?  The end result I am looking for is something in the Rails/SQL syntax rather than a Rails helper.

Comment: WHat version of Rails are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441791/how-to-select-where-id-in-array-rails-activerecord-without-exception

Comment: You mixed up two different array initialisations.