# Matching array values in PostgreSQL with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have a goal to see all contacts, where field `visible_to` in contacts table  equal to 1. My `visible_to` is `:integer, array: true`.

However, I get the following exception:

`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
LINE 1: ....* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."visible_to" IN (1)  OR...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.: SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."visible_to" IN (1)  ORDER BY created_at DESC`

I searched for answers and as far as I see there is an issue with a type of `visible_to`. However, I couldn't find the solution. I also tried to get benefit from casts hint, but in vain.

My migration:

```
class AddVisibleToToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :contacts, :visible_to, :integer, array: true, default: [], using: 'gin'     
    end 
end
```

Relevant variable from Controller:

```
@contacts_all_user_sorted = Contact.all.where(visible_to: [1]).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Hi. Is it normal that you wrote "defalult" instead of "default" in your migration file ?

Comment: Thx, it was just a typo here. In a migration everything is fine.

Comment: Short preliminary debrief from me on the reasons of the problem. (1) Again and again and again RTFM and not only ActiveRecord but [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html) as well (2) I was too heavy dependent on similar question and [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441791/how-to-select-where-id-in-array-rails-activerecord-without-exception), that was not relevant for me (_because_ _of_ _PostgreSQL_ _specific?_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From these two websites:

- http://blog.relatabase.com/rails-postgres-arrays
- http://adamsanderson.github.io/railsconf_2013/#11

It seems that this syntax should work:

```
@contacts_all_user_sorted = Contact.all.where("visible_to @> ARRAY[?]", [1])
```

Does it work?

P.S: As @Quertie pointed out in the comments, you may want to cast the value in the case of a String array, by replacing `ARRAY[?]` by `ARRAY[?]::varchar[]`

Comment: This doesn't work on string arrays and gives the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]
`.


Fixed it by changing `ARRAY[?]` to `ARRAY[?]::varchar[]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Qwertie. I will add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your migration seems pretty straight forward and correct.

can you please try this:

```
Contact.where('visible_to IN ?', ['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Ajit, thx for help. Here is an outcome from a console: `Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE (visible_to IN '1','2')
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE (visible_to IN '1','2')
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'1'"
LINE 1: ... "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE (visible_to IN '1','2')
......`

Comment: P.S. And the output error at the end is `output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'1'"`

Comment: seems like your visible_in column is integer. is that correct? \n please try Contact.where('visible_to in (?)', [1,2])

Comment: I was thinking about that as well, but as far I understand from manuals I need to define a type of elements in array, right? I tried your suggestion and in this case I got: `output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer`

Comment: Contact.where(:visible_to => [1,2,3]) try this

Comment: Ajit, the result is `#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer`. It looks like @d34n5 was right and we need to use another syntax for this task.

Comment: whats the datatype on for your visible_to field?

Comment: As I posted above it's `:visible_to, :integer, array: true`