# Get grouped values by multiple ids in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for bad English ))

I have an array of ids in my ruby code.

Example:

```
[[10], [], [10, 1, 3], []]
```

Can I load `User` model from MySQL table `users` in one query by saving grouping?

Example:

```
[[#<User id=10>], [], [#<User id=10>, #<User id=1>, #<User id=3>], []]
```

Environment: Ruby 2.5.1 | Rails 5 | MySQL

**One of found solution:**

I can flat my array of ids and load my model by that array into hash:

```
hash = User.where(id: array.flatten).index_by(&:id)
```

Then, during iterating, through array I can load my objects from hash in the right order like that:

```
array.each do |ids|
  users = ids.map { |id| hash[id] }
  # do smth
end
```

Comment: what is your criteria for grouping?  I think active record only returns arrays, but you can use ruby to create the grouping you want.

Comment: Your example input and output don't match.

Comment: I think you need to scan the main array at least and make a call to database for each element using [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441835/5239030)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple: use flatten method for array:

```
ids = [[123], [], [123, 1, 3, 4], [70, 80]]
user_ids = ids.flatten.reject(&:blank?).uniq
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

edited:
not optimal (recursive) method for your need:

```ruby
def map_users_by_id(ids_array:, users:)
  result = []
  ids_array.each do |array_element|
    if (array_element).is_a? Array
      result << map_users_by_id(ids_array: array_element, users: users)
    else
      result << users[array_element]
    end
  end
  return result
end

ids = [[123], [], [123, 1, 3, 4], [70, 80]]
user_ids = ids.flatten.reject(&:blank?).uniq
users = Hash[User.where(id: user_ids).map{|user|[user.id, user]}]
result = map_users_by_id(ids_array: ids, users: users)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But I need to save my grouping like that:
```[[#<User id=123>], [], [<#User id=123>, #<User id=1>], [<#User id=3>, ...]]```

In your example I will get just uniq array of my model.