# How can I get an ActiveRecord::Relation from an array of records sorted in a specific order of their IDs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails engine that defines a class method `top(count)` on a model of choice. What this method does is grab `count` IDs from a sorted set (ZSET) in Redis. The idea is that each item of this model has a score, and this method is to return the "best" records. The method essentially looks like this:

```
def self.top(count = 1)
  ids = redis.zrevrange(self.score_set, 0, count - 1)
  items = self.find ids

  if count == 1
    return items.first
  else
    return items.sort { |x, y| ids.index(x.id) <=> ids.index(y.id) }
  end
end
```

As you can see, I currently sort the records after the fact because databases (or the adapters) tend not to maintain order when finding by multiple IDs. For instance, `Model.where('ID IN (?)', ids)` will sort by ascending IDs rather than the order of the passed IDs.

Sorting the items returns an `Array`, but I'd like this method to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead so that my users can chain it with other ActiveRecord query methods. Is there a way I can use the built-in ActiveRecord query methods to maintain order from my array of IDs? Or alternatively, is there a way to construct an `ActiveRecord::Relation` from an array of records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the underlying database you are using. I do not think rails has a pretty way to do this.

I have an application where I am doing the same thing as you. Storing ids in a Redis ZSET and then needing to fetch them in that order. Since we are using MySql we can take advantage of the [field function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

```
Model.where('id in (?)', ids).order("field(id, #{order})")
```

PS: Make sure your `order` variable is sanitized!

Comment: This works great for MySQL, yes, but my gem needs to be database agnostic. I think I'm probably going to give up and just return an Array. I don't think there's a way to do this that works for each of the major databases.

Comment: There's another way too, not as efficient but it still does the job: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564039/204452