# Force order on a result return from ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

I have the following Array (for example):

```
array = [234,675,11,233,99]
```

I than Run something like the following ActiveRecord Query:

```
User.where(id: array)
```

Array returned will be randomly ordered.

However, I want the returned results to be based on the order of the original array (i.e. id=234 to be first and id=99 to be last).

I could loop on the array and fire 5 separated queries, is there better way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicated with:

[ActiveRecord.find(array_of_ids), preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order)

So basically the code should be:

User.find(ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join(',')})")