# ActiveRecord.where(column: array_of_strings) - how to preserve order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, sinatra

This question is a lot like [ActiveRecord.find(array_of_ids), preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order) but about using 'where' and an array of ids that are strings.

Our situation is unfortunately a bit more complex where we receive a JSON string (an `ArchiveObject` has media attached to it through a column, `media`) such as:

```
[{"image_id":"ABCD1234", "type":"Image"},
{"image_id":"ABCD2345", "type":"Image"},
{"image_id":"ABCD3456", "type":"Image"}]
```

Each of these objects do exist in the database, but to make a long story short, we can't use their integer based pk IDs because our database is constantly flushed and rewritten from an export of XML data.

Currently, we are

1. Parsing the JSON
2. Mapping the 'image_id'
3. Performing a `where` to find the relevant objects

Code:

```
images = JSON.parse(current_archive_object.media)
image_ids = images.map { |image| image['image_id'] }
images = ArchiveObject.where(image_id: @image_ids)
```

Thus my question is, is there any way to order the resulting activerecord relation to the original array `image_ids`? Or if I can loop through `image_ids`, is there a way to access a particular object in the relation via one of its column values efficiently?

Extra note:

The reason we went through all this trouble of mapping and `where` is that each image has a caption, url etc. stored in its own row that isn't present in the `media` column of its parent object, thus to prevent database lookups per image, we tried to compile it all into one DB call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer isn't postgresql-specific, but in my project I'd the same problem.

Try solution below

```
images = JSON.parse(current_archive_object.media)
image_ids = images.map { |image| image['image_id'] }
order = "position(image_id::text in '#{image_ids.join(',')}')"
images = ArchiveObject.where(image_id: image_ids).order(order)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I'm receiving `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "ABCD1234" does not exist`, the postgresql statement in the console is (simplified) `SELECT "archive_objects".* FROM "archive_objects"  WHERE "archive_objects"."image_id" IN ('ABCD1234', 'ABCD3456', 'ABCD4567')  ORDER BY image_id=ABCD4567 DESC,image_id=ABCD1234,image_id=ABCD3456`

Comment: Updated my answer with another ordering feature. Try it out.