# Rails where condition and order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

Knowing that by default Rails orders data by ID, how can I order by ids given to the where clause?

```
ids = Bookmark.where(user_id: 7).order(created_at: :desc).pluck(:company_id)
```

Result:

> [146, 140, 128, 4, 2]

Now, when I try to get the companies in the same order from `ids`

```
Company.where(id: ids).pluck(:id)
```

Result:

> [2, 4, 128, 140, 146]

**Expected Result**:

> [146, 140, 128, 4, 2]

My pretended result will be the same in both cases (same order).
The companies should be returned in the same order that the Bookmarks on that company where created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like given a user ID, you want a list of companies sorted by the `created_at` date of the bookmarks that join Users and Companies.

Am I correct in assuming that Users and Companies share a many-to-many relationship through Bookmarks?

If that's the case, the following "join" could work for you!

```
Company.joins(:bookmarks).where('bookmarks.user_id = ?', 7).order('bookmarks.created_at')
```

Of course, in your code, this could be generalized to grab companies for any user!

```
user_id = 42
companies = Company.joins(:bookmarks).where('bookmarks.user_id = ?', user_id).order('bookmarks.created_at')
```

[ActiveRecord "joins" reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669484/how-to-get-value-using-join-table-with-different-values/56680298#56680298

Answer (score 3):

```
Company.includes(:bookmarks) .where(id: ids).order('bookmarks.created_at desc').pluck(:id)
```

Comment: I need the companies sorted by the created_at column from the Bookmark table, not the Company table.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly ordering by `created_at` in `order(created_at: :desc)`

You want to order by `company_id` `ids = Bookmark.where(user_id: 7).order(:company_id).pluck(:company_id)`

Comment: I believe this will sort by the `id` on `bookmarks`, not the `pluck`ed `company_id`.

Comment: @RayBaxter I have updated the question to clarify the order I want in companies.

Comment: @RayBaxter The order(created_at: :desc) is on Bookmarks, but I want the companies from the same order that the Bookmarks had been created.

Comment: @PauloFidalgo If that is the case, then you almost had the correct query in the first place. `ids = Bookmark.where(user_id: 7).order(:created_at).pluck(:company_id)`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to order by... the `company_id`?

`pluck` returns an array, which is why this does NOT work:

```
ids = Bookmark.where(user_id: 7).pluck(:company_id).order(company_id: :desc)
## undefined method `order' for Array
```

Instead, you can call [sort](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort) on the array.

```
ids = Bookmark.where(user_id: 7).pluck(:company_id).sort
```

That should do the trick

Comment: I am not sorting the array, I want the companies from the same order from the creation date of Bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this:

```
company_by_id = Company.find(ids).index_by(&:id) # Gives you a hash indexed by ID
ids.collect {|id| company_by_id[id].id }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer for PostgreSQL, please check it there

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved the question:

```
Bookmark.includes(:company).where(user_id: current_user).order(created_at: :desc)
```

and when iterating over the elements I use:

`record.company` instead of `record`.

This way I have the companies from the same order that the Bookmarks where created.

Comment: I encountered this problem before. I ended up using Gunchars answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order). I think that is faster than iterating the bookmark records in this answer of yours. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I need to iterate in the view. But thanks for pointing it.