# How can I insert at every nth item based on criteria in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have a `posts` table, with a boolean column `sponsored`.

Is there any way I can get an ActiveRecord relation where every nth post is a (ideally random) sponsored post? Bonus points if n can vary.

I would prefer to do this in the database rather than Ruby arrays, since I would like to be able to paginate my results the same way I do now.

My current best idea is something like this:

```
sponsored_ids = Post.where(sponsored: true).select :id
normal_ids = Post.where(sponsored: false).select :id
ordered_ids = inject_sponsored_posts(sponsored_ids, normal_ids)
Post.where(id: ordered_ids) # But this wont preserve order :/
```

Which isn't particularly ideal.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Why should a random post be tagged as sponsored?

Comment: I just mean randomly selected from the pre existing sponsored posts. The use case is that advertisers sponsor a post and expect it do be shown to users.

Comment: The accepted answer from this post MIGHT help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order . It's specifically for MySQL, but maybe you could find a similar postgres feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping through your posts, you could use [`.each_slice`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice):

```
<% @posts.each_slice(x) do |post_group| %>
   <% post_group.each do |post| %>

   <% end %>

   <% ... spondored ... %>
<% end %>
```

--

I can delete this if it's too low ball. Injecting an `id` into the SQL query is the most efficient way (as per the comments).