# How to query .where on array of clients?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, active-relation

**Using Rails 5.**

I have an ordered array of clients. It's not possible for me to get an AR out of it, and this is the only way I can get these clients.

And I want to show only the clients where a certain condition is met. .where(category_id: 1), but as this is not an AR, I can't run a .where(category_id: 1) on the array of clients.

How do I achieve this? With a Scope? But how specifically? And is this still used in Rails 5?

I am basically in the same situation as second-most-upvoted in this question and basically I have an array with my clients:
[ActiveRecord.find(array_of_ids), preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order) (Couldn't make the other suggestions work in the thread about turning my array into an AR)

Anyways, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate through the array and save the values in a variable that can be accessed by `.where(category_id: )`

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

array.each do |a|

  if xyz.where("category_id (?)", a) == true
   do something here
  end

end
```

So something like `xyz.where("category_id (?)", a)`should be possible now.

Comment: You can also write that as `xyz.where(category_id: a)`

Comment: Thanks - that is a solution to what I asked. I ended up actually getting it reverted back into an AR with the order_as_specified gem!