# Rails search condition following order of a sequentially generated collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An array of IDs are being collected

```
@valid_ts = []
@valid_ts = @valid_ts << dst_1.id 
@valid_ts = @valid_ts << dst_2.id
```

*note : each row shown above is in fact run for each member of a collection (i.e. dst_1.size > 1)*
When comes time to query the database

```
slots = Timeslot.where('id IN (?)', @valid_ts).all
```

the goal is to generate the collection in the order that these members were added to the collection.  Rails defaults to `updated_at`, otherwise the query has to invoke one of the class's attributes, none of which are useful for the targetted context.

How can the originating order of the array be respected with Rails?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Mysql` you can use `field` function.

```
Timeslot.where(id: @valid_ts).order("field(id, #{ids.join ','})")
```

If you are using `Postgres` you can use `position` function. -

```
Timeslot.where(id: @valid_ts).order("position(id::text in '#{ids.join(',')}')")
```

But ActiveRecord can perform for both if you are using `rails >= 5.2.0` as it is added from that version. Most likely it is also backported in `rails 5.0`. The [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22653) and the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2c5acb20dd944cc061a03e8d1ca6d3e469c0d46e) and the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

```
Timeslot.find(@valid_ts)
```

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order) post for more ideas.

Comment: `Timeslot.find(@valid_ts)`  will not work, as Rails has no idea of the ordering criteria and defaults to updated_at attribute.  Your link does provide a good direction for AR query.  I have thus re-cast the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912122/activerecord-condition-with-order-based-on-ad-hoc-order-of-attributes , as there is peculiarity.  Will delete this one subsequently given it may be too miseleading.

Comment: Did you try it? I tried it myself in one of my Table. It returned as I provided the array.
It's in the rails commits.
pull request - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22653
the commit - https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2c5acb20dd944cc061a03e8d1ca6d3e469c0d46e

Comment: Edited the answer with links as which that The `find` returned records are in the same order as the ids you provide. If you want the results to be sorted by database, you can use ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where(taken from the docs).

Comment: The rails 5.2 syntax is correct, however for rails 4, the syntax for Postgre searching is failing with error `undefined local variable or method 'ids'`