# Preserving the order of an array when using .where in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am passing an array of ids to a `.where` in Rails, but the way it's returned doesn't preserve the order. For example, here's the array:

```
2.5.1 :043 > company_ids
 => [83, 79, 52, 44, 82]
```

I am looking for all pages that have those company IDs, but returned in the order of those company IDs that were provided. This is the result if I try to compare:

```
2.5.1 :044 > Page.where(company_id: company_ids).pluck(:company_id)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT "pages"."company_id" FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."company_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)  [["company_id", 83], ["company_id", 79], ["company_id", 52], ["company_id", 44], ["company_id", 82]]
 => [83, 82, 52, 44, 79]
```

I ran across this stackoverflow post ([ActiveRecord.find(array_of_ids), preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order/26868980#26868980)) that seems to provide a solution, but it doesn't work for me. When trying to use `Page.where(company_id: company_ids).order("field(company_id, #{company_ids.join ','})")` as suggested in the stackoverflow post, I get the following error:

```
2.5.1 :042 > Page.where(company_id: company_ids).order("field(company_id, #{company_ids.join ','})")
  Page Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."company_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ORDER BY field(company_id, 83,79,52,44,82) LIMIT $6  [["company_id", 83], ["company_id", 79], ["company_id", 52], ["company_id", 44], ["company_id", 82], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function field(bigint, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist)
LINE 1: ...ts"."company_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ORDER BY field(comp...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."company_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ORDER BY field(company_id, 83,79,52,44,82) LIMIT $6
```

I just simply want to call `Pages.where(company_id: company_ids)` and get the pages back based on order of `company_ids` that was provided.

As a workaround, I am using this:

```
company_ids = companies.order("full_name ASC").pluck(:id)
pages = []
company_ids.each {|c| pages << Page.find_by(company_id: c)}
```

but seems like that would be inefficient if there are thousands of records. or even just hundreds.

Comment: I think they're ordered by their created_at automatically.  If you want a custom order, Why not create a custom scope to order by a custom field?

Comment: Not familiar with that process. I just thought i could append something to order by the scope as mentioned in the other post. Seems like I'm just missing something small from the other solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're using a MySQL function (field), but the RDBMS you're using is PostgreSQL.

You can try with `position`, using the row `company_id` and the array of ids concatenated:

```
Page.where(company_id: company_ids).order("position(company_id::text in '#{ids.join(',')}')")
```

Use:

```
Page.where(company_id: company_ids).order(Arel.sql("position(company_id::text in '#{ids.join(',')}')"))
```

if you're getting a deprecation warning.

There also exists the possibility to use `find`, which as stated in the doc says *The returned records are in the same order as the ids you provide*. Although I don't know if it applies for your case.