# ActiveRecord order by external array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I have an array of ids, stored in some external storage (rails cache or redis). In controller's action I fetch this data and select object using it, i.e.

```
ids = [5, 1, 17, 84] # really fetched from external source
result = MyModel.where(:id => ids)
```

I also want it to be ordered just the same as ids in array_of ids:

```
ids == result.map(&:id) # => true
```

As workaround I use sorting by mysql FIELD function:

```
MyModel.where(:id => ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join ', '})")
```

But I don't like this approach as it is mysql specific and creates very long queries in case of big `ids` array.
Is there better, DB-agnostic way to do it? Fetching unsorted data from DB and sorting on ruby side is undesirable because it's resource-expensive and hard to use with pagination.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord.find(array\_of\_ids), preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680627/activerecord-findarray-of-ids-preserving-order)

Answer (score 15):

I just released a gem ([order_as_specified](https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified)) that allows you to do native SQL ordering like this:

```
MyModel.where(id: ids).order_as_specified(id: ids)
```

It returns an ActiveRecord relation, and thus can be chained with other methods:

```
MyModel.where(id: ids).order_as_specified(id: ids).limit(3)
```

If you're curious, under the hood it's constructing:

```
... ORDER BY ID='5' DESC, ID='1' DESC, ID='17' DESC, ID='84'  DESC
```

Comment: This is quite a clever solution. Rather than add a gem, I just wrote a simple one-liner for my case that does what I need: `sql = ids.map.with_index { |id, index|  index == ids.length - 1 ? "ID='#{id}' DESC" : "ID='#{id}' DESC, " }.join('')`. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: A shorter way to write the code in the comment above would be `sql = ids.map { |id| "ID='#{id}' DESC" }.join(', ')`

Comment: This just solved a massive headache for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind receiving an array instead of an ActiveRecord Collection, you can use:

```
result = MyModel.find(ids).sort_by {|m| ids.index(m.id)}
```

Comment: most concise way, dont need a gem

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7 introduced [in_order_of](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of), which solves this exact problem. You can just write

```
MyModel.in_order_of(:id, ids)
```

Note that using it automatically introduces a where clause on the ids as well

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the array is always the same you could add a cached order column to you're database table.

MyModel.order("cached_order")

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. Array of ids changes fast. For example it can be list of last visited #show pages, stored in Redis.