# Rails Sorting the record based on the array passed in where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to sort my where condition result in the order i am passing the values in array . what i am doing is i have an array of ids

```
ids = [80, 20, 3, 91, 84, 90, 98, 97, 68, 99, 92, 73]
```

When i am passing this array to where condition like :

```
products = Product.where(id: ids)
```

its returning the result active record relation  in different order (random order)something like :

```
=>[ 20 ,84, 3,98 , .............. ]
```

(this is active record relation object i have mention only ids here )

But i want it to return the object in same order i am passing the the values like (In active record relation object not an array)

```
=> [80, 20, 3, 91, 84, 90, 98, 97, 68, 99, 92, 73]
```

How can i do this .

Comment: want to sort it by the order in which i am passing it into array not by  id

Answer (score 5):

I have got the solution of this just need to do

In product model inside product.rb file put :

```
 def self.order_by_ids(ids)
    order_by = ["case"]
    ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
      order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
    end
    order_by << "end"
    order(order_by.join(" "))
  end
```

And query will be :

```
products = Product.where(:id => ids).order_by_ids(ids)
```

Here ids will be array of id's

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort by using indices of your ids array:

```
products = Product.where(id: ids).sort_by { |prod| ids.index(prod.id) }
```

Plus it's database agnostic, and it's ok to do in Ruby as you won't have millions of ids in any case.

Comment: Actually this will return an array not active record relation.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is for mysql only**

There is a function in mysql called [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

So you can do something like

```
products = Product.where(id: ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join ','})")
```

Comment: I am looking for postgress actually . is there any way to achieve same wit postgress .

Answer (score 0):

**In Postgres**

```
hot_offer_ids = ["7081", "7083", "6917", "5075"]
values = ''
hot_offer_ids.each_with_index do |offer_id, index|
  values += ", " if index > 0
  values += %((#{offer_id}, #{index}))
end
hot_offers = Offer.joins("join (VALUES #{values}) as x(id, ordering) on offers.id = x.id").order("x.ordering")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem ([order_as_specified](https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified)) that allows you to do native SQL ordering like this:

```
Model.where(id: ids).order_as_specified(id: ids)
```

Reference Answer : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505079/activerecord-order-by-external-array/29039262)