# Rails, ActiveRecord, query id in array of ints, keep order of passed array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am thinking about the best solution for a problem.
Let's say that we have a list of ids of ActiveRecord model:

```
ids = [1, 100, 5, 30, 4, 2, 88, 44]
```

Then I would like to make query that selects all users for example with ids from the list but to keep the order.
If I do

```
User.where(id: ids)
```

the response will be a list of users with asc order by id, but I want the order to be the same as in the array.

What do you think that it's the best solution here? Select all users and then to manipulate the list of ActiveRecord objects? Maybe there is a more clever way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: what db engine do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801824/clean-way-to-find-activerecord-objects-by-id-in-the-order-specified

Answer (score 25):

With reference to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list), for postgresql,

```
User.where(id: ids).order("position(id::text in '#{ids.join(',')}')")
```

Answer (score 12):

regard less of MySQL and Postgresql, **if you have a small size of ids,**

```
User.where(id: ids).sort_by { |u| ids.index(u.id) }
```

Comment: This answer works great - my comment is not a criticism, just info incase someone else runs into the same issue. Be aware that the `sort_by` used in the answer returns an `array`, not an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object that some gems (like the pagination gem I was using) require to work properly. The answer below by `Vic` worked for me since I was using postgres and needed an ordered AR relation.

Comment: @NathanBeck it is. `sort_by` itself is an `Array` method

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks for the answer. 
You Rocks!!!!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using MySQL, you can use `FIELD` to order results:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_in_order(ids)
    self.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})")
  end
end

User.find_in_order([1, 100, 5, 30, 4, 2, 88, 44])
```

Comment: Note that, if your column data is string or text, wrap your inputted value within escaped double quotes first. ie `#{ids.map{|x| "\"#{x}"\"}}.join(',')` . Otherwise, you will still get the id sorted result.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility for Postgres (9.4 or later):

```
ordered_ids = [1, 100, 5, 30, 4, 2, 88, 44]
User.joins("join unnest('{#{ordered_ids.join(',')}}'::int[]) WITH " \
           "ORDINALITY t(id, ord) USING (id)").reorder('t.ord')
```

Notice that the reorder is extremely important.

Solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35456954

Comment: common column name "id" appears more than once in left table

Answer (score 1):

```
users_by_id = User.find(ids).index_by(&:id) # Gives you a hash indexed by ID
ids.collect {|id| users_by_id[id] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres you can use `intarray`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_in_order(ids)
    self.where(id: ids).order("idx(array[#{ids.join(',')}], id)")
  end
end
```

you should init module first

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching by primary key you can use `find`, which accepts an array and guarantees order.

```
User.find(ids)
```

Few "downsides"/"extra features":

- it will return an array instead of relation, so it needs to be called at the very end of your chaining.
- it will raise `ActiveRecord::NotFound` exception if any of the given ids is not present in the database

Comment: FYI: the question is tagged `ruby-on-rails-4` and the sorting behavior was introduced in Rails 5.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get a result of Model::ActiveRecord_Relation

```
order(Arel.sql("field(id, ids.join(', ') asc"))
```

Arel.sql is required to prevent the message in log:

> Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL)
>   called with non-attribute argument(s)