# Sort ActiveRecord collection by different attributes depending on a third attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an `Order` model with those attributes:

- **created_at** *DateTime*
- **delivery_at** *DateTime*
- **status** *String*

What I am trying to do, is to sort two collections by `created_at` or `delivery_at` depending on its `status`.

On the model, I created a method which checks the status order and return `created_at` or `delivery_at` datetime.

```
def status_date
  if status == 'on_delivery'
    delivered_at.to_datetime
  else
    created_at.to_datetime
  end
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
created = Order.where(status: 'open')
on_delivery = Order.where(stauts: 'on_delivery')

orders = created + on_delivery
orders.sort_by(&:status_date)
```

Which is not working.

I am trying to achieve a chronological list of orders, but DateTime should be related to its status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in the database by querying both statuses at once and then using an SQL CASE expression for the ordering:

```
case status
when 'open' then created_at -- if the status is open then use created_at
else delivered_at           -- otherwise use delivered_at
end
```

You only have two statuses so those branches are sufficient.

Putting it together:

```
orders = Order.where(status: %w[open on_delivery])
              .order(Arel.sql("case status when 'open' then created_at else delivered_at end"))
```

The [`Arel.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897280/479863) is needed to get an SQL string past `#order` without complaint in Rails5 (and will be mandatory in Rails6).

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. The most simple query I can build is: `Order.by_date(date).where(status: %w[open on_delivery]).order(Arel.sql("CASE status WHEN 'open' THEN created_at ELSE delivered_at END"))`. The by_date it's just a scope to fetch from beginning to end of given date. Anyway, the query returns me the orders well, but the order seemed to be grouped by its status (one date I got on_delivery-open-on_delivery grouped result, other open-on_delivery), and there isn't any grouping.

Comment: That "most simple" query is the same as mine but you've introduced the `by_date` scope. The order is by timestamp but the timestamp used depends on the `status` which is what you're looking for, right? I don't know what you mean "there isn't any grouping".

Comment: Aah. The problem was other dates coming up, so I did: `Arel.sql("case status when 'open' then created_at::time else delivered_at::time end")`