# How would you replace this SQL query in Ruby so that you only use ActiveRecord code?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

This is actually working (it returns the 5 artists with the most amount of tracks in a database)

```
def top_five_artists(genre_name)
  # TODO: return the 5 artists with the more tracks of genre `genre_name`
  Artist.joins(albums: { tracks: :genre }).where(genres: { name: genre_name }).group(:name).order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(5)
end
```

but throws the following warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments
>   are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "COUNT(*)
>   DESC". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1. This
>   method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request
>   parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by
>   wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from top_five_artists at
>   /home/maxichalbaud/code/maxichalbaud/fullstack-challenges/03-AR-Database/03-ActiveRecord-Basics/Optional-01-Mapping-Existing-Database/app/queries.rb:18)

How would you refactor the "COUNT(*) DESC" line?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [**DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48897070/479863) because I can't think of how to order by `count(*) desc` without getting into a bunch of incomprehensible AREL code. So you could `order(Arel.sql('count(*) desc'))` to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
def top_five_artists(genre_name)
  Artist.joins(albums: { tracks: :genre })
        .where(genres: { name: genre_name })
        .group(:name)
        .order(Arel.sql('count(*) DESC'))
        .limit(5)
end
```

First, you can use `order(Arel.sql('count(*) DESC'))` to get rid of the warning of deprecation as [mu_is_too_short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) mentioned above, then, you can write your code in multiple lines so that RuboCop won’t bother you with "This line is too long".

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.